# In C++, how do I template a class to use another class and a member of that class?

Tags: c++, templates

So I want to be able to use a data structure we've designed for homework in different situations. Specifically, I have a minHeap but I want to template it to take objects. Since the minHeap has to compare elements to maintain the structure and return the minimum efficiently, is it possible to template my minHeap class to take any given object and a member of that object as the thing to be comparing between elements?

My idea was something like:

```
template<class TYPE, class TYPE_COMPARE>
class minHeap {
...(stuff inside)...
};
```

But I realized I can't really access something in an object of type TYPE using TYPE_COMPARE. Which is why I was wondering if I could template a class to take another class and a member of that class.

EDIT:
Someone suggested adding my code for clarification. This is what I'm imagining it would look like, but I have a strong feeling it doesn't work like this.

This is the header file for my minHeap.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class TYPE, TYPE::class MEMBER>
class minHeap {
private:
    vector<TYPE> nodes;
    int current;

    int parent(int i) {
        return (i-1)/2;
    }

    int leftChild(int i) {
        return 2*i+1;
    }

    int rightChild(int i) {
        return 2*i+2;
    }

    void bubbleUp(int i) {
        if(i > 0) {
            int p = parent(i);
            if(nodes[i]::MEMBER < nodes[p]::MEMBER) {
                swap(nodes[i], nodes[p]);
                bubbleUp(p);
            }
        }
    }

    void bubbleDown(int i) {
        if(i < current) {
            int a = leftChild(i);
            int b = rightChild(i);

            if(b > current && a <= current) {
                if(nodes[i]::MEMBER > nodes[a]::MEMBER) {
                    swap(nodes[i], nodes[a]);
                }
            }
            else if(b <= current && a <= current) {
                if(nodes[i]::MEMBER > nodes[a]::MEMBER || nodes[i]::MEMBER > nodes[b]::MEMBER) {
                    if(nodes[a] < nodes[b]) {
                        swap(nodes[i], nodes[a]);
                        bubbleDown(a);
                    }
                    else {
                        swap(nodes[i], nodes[b]);
                        bubbleDown(b);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

public:
    minHeap() {
        current = -1;
    }

    void insert(TYPE x) {
        current++;
        nodes.push_back(x);
        bubbleUp(current);
    }

    TYPE extractMin() {
        TYPE min = nodes[0];
        swap(nodes[0], nodes[current]);
        current--;
        nodes.pop_back();
        bubbleDown(0);
        return min;
    }

    bool empty() {
        if(current < 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Have [a look](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) at the standard library how it does this thing.

Comment: I can't really tell what you're trying to do. Could you post some code that demonstrates what you're trying to do? (no matter whether it actually works or not)

Comment: @5gon12eder I'll take a look in awhile. Initially I just wanted to use the standard priority_queue, but couldn't figure out to how pass the class member I wanted to use as the basis for comparison.

Comment: @immibis I'll update it with some code to better show what I mean.

Comment: @morr36 I wanted to point you to the `Compare` template parameter.  You can tell a  `std::set` how to compare (sort) its elements if operator `<` is not appropriate.

Comment: @immibis Ah. If I can still access the member of the class I'm passing as a template in a usual manner, then I wouldn't need to use something like `std::less` and still use the `<` operator.

Still, I'm trying to understand how I'd access a member in that class. I don't see something like that in the example for `std::set`, but I might just be missing it.

Comment: @morr36 You can do things like `TYPE t1, t2; cout << (t1 < t2 ? "less" : "greater");` - it won't cause an error until you try to create a `min_heap<SomethingThatDoesntHaveALessThanOperator>`

Comment: assuming from your code `MEMBER` is a data member, whats issue with simply doing `nodes[i].MEMBER` ?

Comment: Are you looking for [member pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members) ?

Comment: @P0W I wasn't sure how the syntax would be. That seems just as fine to me. Still not sure if the declarations for the template is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly access `TYPE`. But as you only have the type, you can only access static members.

```
class MyType
{
    static void SomeStaticFunction();
};

template<class TYPE>
class minHeap
{
    void fn()
    {
        TYPE::SomeStaticFunction();
    }
};
```

If you want to access non-static members, then naturally you will need an instance to operate on:

```
class MyType
{
    void SomeNonStaticFunction();
};

template<class TYPE>
class minHeap
{
    void fn(const TYPE& inst)
    {
        inst.SomeNonStaticFunction();
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't think that this is what the OP is trying to do.  It seems to me that he is rather looking for a custom comparator.

Comment: So I'm not really trying to use a function of the class. I want to use a member *variable* (should've mentioned that). I need to be able to give it an object and access, say, an integer member that the object has, for use in comparisons.